# What is branching factor of mysql myisam's b-tree

Tags: mysql, myisam

I am doing some research but I am struggling to find what is branching factor of MYISAM's b-tree, e.g. how many keys per page (node).

I also would like to know how the char/varchar keys are stored - are they stored in full length or just first "meaningful" characters.

> By "meaningful" characters I mean:
>
> ```
> create table a(
>    name varchar(1000) primary key
> );
>
> insert into a('london');
> ```
>
> "london" key is 1000 characters long (assuming ASCII), but the key
> itself is just 6 characters (7 with null character, if we represent it as C-string).

Comment: why minus without explanation?

Comment: I agree, if there is something wrong with the question make a comment on how it can be improved

Comment: Could it be `data-controller="s-tooltip"  title="This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"` by chance?

Comment: If it was like his, I believe there would be at least 5 answers as comments?

Comment: [read the code](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/tree/8.0/storage/myisam) or run your sql with a debugger attached to the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is about 8 bytes of overhead per index entry.  So, if the key is typically 6 bytes, and the `key_buffer` block size is 1KB, and the BTree is 69% full:

```
1024 * .69 / (8+6)
```

says there will be about 50 rows.

So, 3 levels of BTree can handle up to 50^3 = 125K rows.

The .69 comes from assuming lots of random inserts -- leading to each block oscillating between 100% full just before a block split and 50% after.

There may be an obscure `SELECT` against the `information_schema` to get the exact value for the indexes.  (I know of one for InnoDB.)

Comment: any idea if I "throw" varchar(1000) as a key?

Comment: @Nick - `name varchar(1000) primary key` -- The `PRIMARY KEY` is both `UNIQUE` and a `KEY` (aka `INDEX`).  Don't add another index on the same column(s); it will be a waste.  Meanwhile, what does `SHOW TABLE STATUS` say for the table?

Comment: my question is related to development, not to how to use MySQL. Isn't primary key b-tree / b+ tree too?

Comment: In MyISAM each index, including the `PRIMARY KEY` is stored in a separate BTree (not B+Tree).  MyISAM data is stored in a separate file (the `.MYD`) with no structure. 
 MyISAM indexes "point" to the data via either a row number (if `FIXED`) or a byte offset (if `DYNAMIC`).  MySQL's InnoDB is quite different; the `PRIMARY KEY` and the data exist in one B+Tree.  Each secondary index exists in its own B+Tree.